# convert chars to integer correct way

Tags: c

Just trying to make sure I got it right.
On SO I encountered an answer on a question: how to store chars in int like this:

```
unsigned int final = 0;
final |= ( data[0] << 24 );
final |= ( data[1] << 16 );
final |= ( data[2] <<  8 );
final |= ( data[3]       );
```

But to my understanding this is wrong isn't it?
Why: say `data` has stored the integer in little endian way (e.g., `data[0]=LSB_ofSomeInt)`.
Then if machine executing above code is little endian, `final` will hold correct value, 
else if the machine running above code is big endian it will hold a wrong value, isn't it?

Just trying to make sure I got this right, I am not going to ask more question in this direction for now.

Comment: @H2CO3: this is really not duplicate, please remove that link

Comment: why isn't it a duplicate? You asked basically the very same question.

Comment: No: there data was always stored in little endian way. Here, depending on how data is stored (e.g., little or big endian) the result will be either correct, or wrong

Comment: regardless of that, your question is the same: "is this method of storing data good regarding endianness, and if no, how do I fix it?" There isn't really need for two separate question for a little-endian and mixed-endian case. Even the answers to the two questions say the same thing.

Comment: *I am not going to ask more question in this direction for now* you are free to ask more question on the subject provided you are not asking the same questions.

Comment: It's not the same really, plus I was not asking to fix anything here. Ok, let's close down this topic

Comment: @H2CO3: now because of that people started downvoting my other question :(

Comment: @dmcr_code I am sorry about that. It shouldn't be downvotes, that's not the dupe. But next time make sure not to ask a question twice.

Answer (score 3):

Do not do this when you have functions like [htonl](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) etc.

Takes the hassle out of things

Comment: `htonl`, etc. are not functions from the C library, so not all systems provide them.

Comment: @ouah - Lets be very pedantic - sometimes they are not even functions.

Comment: sorry, it's not pedantic. A lot (if not most) of C code being written today is code for embedded systems and I can tell you they usually don't to provide the POSIX function implementations.

Comment: "A lot (if not most) of C code being written today is code for embedded systems " - Evidence for this assertion? BTW it is a #define that can be copied

Answer (score 1):

This code does not depend on the endianness of the platform: `data[0]` is always stored as the most significant byte of the `int`, followed by the rest, and `data[3]` is always the least significant byte.

Whether that's "right" or "wrong" depends on how the integer has been encoded in the `data` array itself.

There is one problem though: if `data` has been declared using `char` rather than `unsigned char`, the signed `data[i]` will be promoted first to a signed `int` and you end up setting many more bits than you intended.

Comment: I think you are saying similar to what I said. But imagine someone encoded `data` in a little endian way. data[0] is LSB of some integer, then if above code is run on big endian machine, `final` will not have desired value, isn't it?

Comment: If `data[0]` is the LSB of some integer the result is incorrect on both little and big endian machines. The only thing that matters is how the input has been encoded, the machine is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes I think you are right that is what I meant. if data[0] is LSB of some integer, actually above code won't work, because it treats data[0] as MSB of some integer, right? ok I think we are done with it

Comment: `data[0]` has to hold the most significant byte of the value when `data` elements are stored. Also the signedness of `char` is implementation defined, so the sign extension will occur only if `char` is signed.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong in little and big endian systems.

If `data` elements are of type `char`, you then need to cast all `data` elements to `unsigned char` before doing the bitwise left shift, otherwise you may encounter sign extension on `data` elements with negative values. The signedness of `char` is implementation defined and `char` can be a signed type.

Also `data[0] << 24` (or even `(unsigned char) data[0] << 24`)  will invoke undefined behavior if `data[0]` is a negative value as the resulting value is then not representable in an `int` and so you'll need an extra cast to `unsigned int`.

The best is to declare  an `unsigned char` array for `data` and then cast each `data` elements to `unsigned int` before the left shift.

Now assuming you cast it correctly, this will work only if `data[0]` holds the most significant byte of your value.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the obvious problem of platform-specific byte-ordering (which other answers have addressed), you should be careful about promotion of data types.

I'm assuming that `data` is an array of type `unsigned char`. In which case, the  expression

```
data[0] << 24
```

is zero; you just left shifted an 8-bit operand 24 bits! I haven't compiled it to check, or reviewed the type promotion rules, but I believe, the way you have parenthesized it, 
`data[0] << 24` is still an `unsigned char`. It gets promoted when you bit-wise or the result with `final`. At best, it leaves too much to interpretation. A safer, more explicit way to do this is to bit-wise or first, then shift:

```
final |= data[0]; final <<= 8;
final |= data[1]; final <<= 8;
final |= data[2]; final <<= 8;
final |= data[3]; final <<= 8;
```

or you could promote explicitly and then shift:

```
final |= ((unsigned int)data[0]) << 24;
final |= ((unsigned int)data[1]) << 16;
final |= ((unsigned int)data[2]) << 8;
final |= ((unsigned int)data[3]);
```

Of course, this doesn't deal with the endianness problem at all. But that may or may not be a problem, depending on where `data` came from.